# Weird Comparison of UITextField and UILabel

Tags: ios, if-statement, comparison, uitextfield, uilabel

How come this happens? Using the code...

```
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    if(textField.text == label.text) {
        NSLog(@"Correct!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error?");
        NSLog(textField.text);
        NSLog(label.text);
    }
}
```

The statement evaulates to be false and prints...

`Error?`

```
Word
Word
```

The words are the same, but the if statement fails... Why is this? I have no clue why this is happening if it is printing the exact same words but the statement is comparing them to be false?

Is it something I am doing wrong in the if statement? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString` is a class. The proper way to see if two `NSString` objects (or objects of any class) have the same value is to use `isEqual:`. In the case of `NSString` you can use `isEqualToString:`.

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:label.text]) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I figured this was the way to do it but I didn't know the Objective C method. Will accept when I can.

Comment: What delegate? There is no delegate involved in this line of code. Do you mean "method"? `isEqualToString:` is a "method", not a delegate.

Comment: That is what I meant, poor word choice. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) I am just learning Objective C and iOS programming so I am sorry to be a bother.

Comment: No bother. If it were a bother I wouldn't have answered. Enjoy the learning. :)

Answer (score 1):

The sign == compares the memory location. It sees if you are referring to the same object or not.

The method "isEqualToString: " should be used to compare string values inside variables.